# Smarter way to block asynchronous content in userscript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asynchronous, greasemonkey

I am using Greasemonkey scripts to block content that annoys me on various websites. However, some content is loaded asynchronously, meaning that using a "onDocumentReady" kind of construct, such as jQuery's

```
$(function() {
  // do stuff
});
```

is not possible.

I have done

```
setInterval(
  function() {
    // do stuff
  }
  , 1000
);
```

but I wonder if there is a smarter way to do this?

Comment: Look into [`MutationObserver`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver).

Answer (score 0):

As Xufox said, the answer is [MutationObserver](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver). I have solved it with the following script:

```
(new MutationObserver(function() {
  // do stuff
})).observe(document.body,
            {attributes: true,
             childList: true,
             characterData: true});
```